# ROS Kinetic on Raspbian Stretch E:Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-freenect-launch E:Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-depthimage-to-laserscan

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, freenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am planning to work on using the Kinect for map building and obstacle avoidance. I have installed ROS-Kinetic successfully by following this [ROS wiki installation](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi). I am following this [installation guide](https://roboticsweekends.blogspot.com/2017/12/how-to-connect-kinect-to-raspberry-pi-2.html) to install Kinect with ROS Kinetic. When I try these commands:

```
sudo apt install ros-kinetic-freenect-launch 
sudo apt install ros-kinetic-depthimage-to-laserscan
```

I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-depthimage-to-laserscan

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E:Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-freenect-launch
```

Can someone help me solve the issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306280/ros-kinetic-on-raspbian-stretch-e:unable-to-locate-package-ros-kinetic-freenect-launch-e:unable-to-locate-package-ros-kinetic-depthimage-to-laserscan/) by [ZeroSan](https://answers.ros.org/users/38110/zerosan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2018-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The installation tutorial you link to installs ROS *from sources*. That means that you download the sources for the relevant packages and then compile them on your target (in this case an RPi).

You cannot later mix that with binary packages that you install with `apt`.

Starting from source means that you'll have to build *every* pkg you want to use later from source as well.

Refer to the [Maintaining a Source Checkout](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi) on the same page to see how you can do that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drtritm](https://answers.ros.org/users/50806/drtritm/) on 2020-03-02**:
Can I clone a source into src folder in workspace and catkin_make in this situation, I mean in the instruction if  I want to install any package I have to list it in this command: rosinstall_generator ros_comm ros_control joystick_drivers --rosdistro kinetic --deps --wet-only --tar > kinetic-custom_ros.rosinstall
But if the package I want to install only available in source??